Is there a place to look up who gets these spells in The Lost City?
In the Goodman Games - The Lost City Conversion, in Appendix A there are several new spells.  But nowhere do I see which classes are supposed to have access to the spells.  I know from earlier in the module that the one faction has one of the spells available in spell books, so thus it's at least a Wizard spell.  But I don't see any hints as to the distribution of the other spells.
Is it somewhere else in the module or was this an oversight?  I've Googled, but I don't see any references elsewhere.
This module, by the way, is out of print so it can only be purchased on the used market (at an unreasonable markup in my opinion).  Here's an eBay link for reference: D&D 5e The Lost City Various Goodman Games

Can you link to the product you are talking about? Is this a [tag:published-adventures] question?

@Mołot  Thanks, I tagged with published adventures and added an eBay link as not even the vendor (Goodman Games) lists it on their site.

I don't think they are all intended for players.
I have had a look and one spell appears only as part of a trap, so it's basically an excuse for hiding a monster.
Another appears on an NPC spell list, but they are a wisdom caster and it's most likely just added to give that NPC some flavour.
Making one spell available via a spell book is calling one spell out specifically, so that is the only one made available that I can see.
I can't see anything (though I can't prove a negative) that says you can learn the others or add them to any spell lists. The only mention of spell list changes / additions I can see is in the riddle section on page 145.

That's a good thought.  I hadn't considered that as a possibility.  I'm going to wait a bit to see if anyone else has any thoughts.  And thanks greatly for the page reference because it's like finding a needle in a haystack in this book.

@ReginaldBlue for what it is worth I would just add them to whatever spell lists seem ok, or at least let a character learn them once they have encountered them if they seem thematic for any given character
